# How to define bits in GPIO MODER register of stm32

Tags: embedded, stm32

I need to define pin 15 of port D to be general purpose output mode,for that i need to set pins 31,30 to be 01.
GPIOD->MODER is my register
(1<<30) and (1<<31) is shifting 1 to 30 and 31 places
I know bit wise or is | and bitwise and is &
What is the technique for setting these values?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: Please don't use `(1 << 30)` and `(1 << 31)`, after a couple of days you will have no idea what they are, there's a header available from ST which has definitions of all bit positions and will let you write readable code.

Comment: Hello Colin,where can i find the bitfields and their meaning?
Meanwhile  we have on bit 30 1 so its set.
So GPIO->MODER|=0b0100,0000,0...00  for setting 1 in MODER
and we need to reset bit 31 so
GPIO->MODER&=~(0b1000,0000,0...00)
is there an easier method of just putting  a general binary number b2b1b0 into whatever location we want without looking at what b2b1b0 is?
Thanks

Comment: @Lundin he is using CMIS. Not needed for him. He needs to learn bitwise operations only

Comment: @ron398 You'll probably find them in the same header as you're getting `GPIOD` from, search it for `GPIO_MODER`

Answer (score 4):

If you do not want to change any other bits you need to zero them first and then to set them.

```
typedef enum
{
    GPIO_MODER_INPUT = 0b00,
    GPIO_MODER_OUTPUT = 0b01,
    GPIO_MODER_ALTERNATE = 0b10,
    GPIO_MODER_ANALOG   = 0b11,
}GPIO_MODER;

void GPIO_SetMODER(GPIO_TypeDef *gpio, int pin, GPIO_MODER mode)
{
    uint32_t reg = gpio -> MODER;

    reg &= ~(0b11 << (pin * 2));
    reg |= (mode & 0b11) << (pin * 2);

    gpio -> MODER = reg;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GPIOD->MODER = ((GPIOD->MODER & ~(1uL << 31)) | (1uL << 30));
```

Comment: You didn't read the first line of the question.  It clearly says "to be 01", which is exactly what this line does.  Bit 31 is set to zero, bit 30 is set to 1.  There is no reason to first clear the bit that you are going to set.

Comment: another day he will ask how to set another bit. What then?

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: That does not make it acceptable for people to post rude and factually untrue comments.  0__ you need to apologize and delete your offensive comment saying that my answer was incorrect when it is a full and correct answer to the question that was asked.  (It just doesn't contain any extra detail that was not asked for.)